# Recasting nested list of any depth

Tags: r, list, reshape

Assume this simplified example:

```
L <- list()

L$Foo <- list()
L$Foo$Bar <- list()
L$Foo$Bar$VAR <- TRUE

L$Lorem <- list()
L$Lorem$Ipsum <- list()
L$Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor <- list()
L$Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor$VAR <- TRUE
```

I will then melt this list with `reshape2::melt(L)`. That will output the following:

```
  value    L3    L2   L4    L1
1  TRUE   VAR   Bar <NA>   Foo
2  TRUE Dolor Ipsum  VAR Lorem
```

After some operations on certain cells in the value column, I'm then looking to recast this melted list into the exact same nested list structure as `L`—the only difference being that I updated a few of the `value` instances.

Any ideas how to achieve this? Please keep in mind that the nested lists can have any, and varying, depth.

Comment: Is this an option: `tmp <- unlist(L); tmp[] <- FALSE; relist(tmp, L)` ?

Comment: @markus Absolutely, this works well as long as I do my intended operations in a slightly different way than originally planned! Thank you! If you repost your comment as an answer, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is `relist`, after we `unlist`ed `L`

```
tmp <- unlist(L)
# make small changes
tmp[] <- FALSE
relist(tmp, L)
```

Result

```
$Foo
$Foo$Bar
$Foo$Bar$VAR
[1] FALSE



$Lorem
$Lorem$Ipsum
$Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor
$Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor$VAR
[1] FALSE
```

---

`L` looks like

```
$Foo
$Foo$Bar
$Foo$Bar$VAR
[1] TRUE



$Lorem
$Lorem$Ipsum
$Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor
$Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor$VAR
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: It looks like the updated list does not preserve the classes of the original structure. For instance, relisting gives `"TRUE"` (character class), not `TRUE` (logical class). Any thoughts on how to handle that?

Comment: Mmmmh, I get `logical`, when I run `class(relist(tmp, L)$Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor$VAR)`. Might be better to ask a separate question with reference to this one and new example data.

Comment: Yes, the reason for that is my simplified example that didn't involve any character vectors. I posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66251237/relisting-a-flat-list-of-various-depth-preserving-classes) with a more elaborate example and details.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be to use `rrapply()` in the `rrapply`-package which has options `how = "melt"` and `how = "unmelt"` to transform between nested lists and melted data.frames:

```r
library(rrapply)

L <- list(Foo = list(Bar = list(VAR = TRUE)), Lorem = list(Ipsum = list(Dolor = list(VAR = TRUE))))

## melt to data.frame
(L1 <- rrapply(L, how = "melt"))
#>      L1    L2    L3   L4 value
#> 1   Foo   Bar   VAR <NA>  TRUE
#> 2 Lorem Ipsum Dolor  VAR  TRUE

## cast back to nested list
L2 <- rrapply(L1, how = "unmelt")

str(L2)
#> List of 2
#>  $ Foo  :List of 1
#>   ..$ Bar:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ VAR: logi TRUE
#>  $ Lorem:List of 1
#>   ..$ Ipsum:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ Dolor:List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ VAR: logi TRUE

identical(L2, L)
#> [1] TRUE
```

An important advantage with respect to `relist()` is that no list skeleton object is needed (see `?relist`), so we are not constrained by the list format defined in the skeleton object when modifying the melted data.frame, e.g.:

```r
L_unlist <- unlist(as.relistable(L))

## this change has no effect when relisting
## as the original list is used as skeleton
names(L_unlist)[1] <- "Foo.Bar.Test"

relist(L_unlist)
#> $Foo
#> $Foo$Bar
#> $Foo$Bar$VAR
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $Lorem
#> $Lorem$Ipsum
#> $Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor
#> $Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor$VAR
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "relistable" "list"

## here it does behave as expected
L_melt <- rrapply(L, how = "melt")
L_melt[1, "L3"] <- "Test"

rrapply(L_melt, how = "unmelt")
#> $Foo
#> $Foo$Bar
#> $Foo$Bar$Test
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $Lorem
#> $Lorem$Ipsum
#> $Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor
#> $Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor$VAR
#> [1] TRUE
```