# Relisting a flat list of various depth, preserving classes

Tags: r

Assume this simplified example:

```
L <- list()

L$Foo <- list()
L$Foo$Bar <- list()
L$Foo$Bar$X <- TRUE
L$Foo$Bar$Y <- "abc"

L$Lorem <- list()
L$Lorem$Ipsum <- list()
L$Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor <- list()
L$Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor$X <- TRUE
L$Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor$Z <- "xyz"
```

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66250453/recasting-nested-list-of-any-depth/66250842?noredirect=1#comment117129125_66250842), I attempted to recast a nested list of any depth after unlisting it. One answer suggested using `unlist()` and then `relist()`.

However, this suggestion does not preserve the original classes if they vary. For instance, `relist(unlist(L), L)` will return:

```
$Foo
$Foo$Bar
$Foo$Bar$X
[1] "TRUE"

$Foo$Bar$Y
[1] "abc"



$Lorem
$Lorem$Ipsum
$Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor
$Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor$X
[1] "TRUE"

$Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor$Z
[1] "xyz"
```

Notice that `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"` are erroneously characters, not logicals.

Now, one solution is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056133/r-relisting-a-flat-list). However, the answer from this question does not work for any depth level of the nested list. For instance, running `relist2(flatten(L), L)` as suggested from the answer returns:

```
> relist2(flatten(L), L)
$Foo
$Foo$Bar.X
$Foo$Bar.X[[1]]
[1] TRUE


$Foo$Bar.Y
$Foo$Bar.Y[[1]]
[1] "abc"



$Lorem
$Lorem$Ipsum.Dolor
$Lorem$Ipsum.Dolor$X
$Lorem$Ipsum.Dolor$X[[1]]
[1] TRUE


$Lorem$Ipsum.Dolor$Z
$Lorem$Ipsum.Dolor$Z[[1]]
[1] "xyz"
```

Here, the classes are preserved, but not all levels are relisted—notice `Ipsum.Dolor` that should have been relisted as `Ipsum$Dolor`.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `type.convert` to change the data types based on the values. `unlist` coerces the data type to a single one (most probably `character` if there is a character element) as a `vector` cannot have multiple data types.  The only info available regarding the data type is in the original 'L'.  The below code fails if there are custom data types i.e. if the logical value should be actually considered as a different type than logical.

```
library(magrittr)
L1 <- relist(unlist(L), L) %>% 
     type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

-comparing the `str`uctures

```
 str(L1)
List of 2
 $ Foo  :List of 1
  ..$ Bar:List of 2
  .. ..$ X: logi TRUE
  .. ..$ Y: chr "abc"
 $ Lorem:List of 1
  ..$ Ipsum:List of 1
  .. ..$ Dolor:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ X: logi TRUE
  .. .. ..$ Z: chr "xyz"
> str(L)
List of 2
 $ Foo  :List of 1
  ..$ Bar:List of 2
  .. ..$ X: logi TRUE
  .. ..$ Y: chr "abc"
 $ Lorem:List of 1
  ..$ Ipsum:List of 1
  .. ..$ Dolor:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ X: logi TRUE
  .. .. ..$ Z: chr "xyz"
```